# Cloudfoundry Installation

Tags: installation, openstack, cloud-foundry

I am newbie to cloud foundry.. however I have a fair knowledge on virtualization and openstack.

I browsed through certain sites to understand the cf. but have no clarity on how does cloudfoundry works.

Can any one let me know the procedure to install cloudfoundry on openstack?

what is the minimum hardware configuration needed?

Is there any tool to install the same?

Do we have to install Bosh cli on a VM?

Hope with some of the answers to the above question I may get the clarity.

Please help.

Thanks,
Anu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anu, installing CF on OpenStack is not trivial, especially if you are looking to do more than just spin up a test environment.  If you want to do this on your own, for production be sure to understand what you are doing by reading all of the documents and get a good handle on CF and service manifests, inception, BOSH deployment, etc.

If you are truly interested in going at this alone, the best place to start is with the CF docs, which will get you started:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org

Then think of deploying CF locally using BOSH lite to get a hang of what you are going to do when doing a full OpenStack deployment:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite

And finally, make use of Google Groups for any questions on BOSH, CF, manifests, etc:

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/bosh-users/topics

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/bosh-dev/topics

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/group/vcap-dev/topics

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, a document that may help you is:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/openstack/

https://bosh.io/docs/init-openstack.html

You will want to install bosh cli and the cloudfoundry cli on an instance that has access to the bosh director and the api server for cloudfoundry, which will depend on the setup of your security groups in Openstack.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.